re assign array with new list of values
Suppose I have a function: void function(int a[3]) {/*..*/}
What is the efficient way of calling this function with values in place
I want to calling as below without creating a new local array[3]
function({1,2,3}) or function([1,2,3])
but that does not work.

Use std::array<int,3>?

Unrelated: Change void function(int a[3]) to void function(int *a) to make it less misleading. Or better yet, use std::array. I would also recommend a good c++ book.

void function(std::array<int,3> a) {};

You can also pass a std::vector.

void function(std::span<int,3> a) {}

function([1,2,3]) is wrong syntax, but you might have function({1,2,3}).

Because this function takes a pointer, you have to create an array somewhere anyway.

Alternatively, you might consider passing std::initializer_list instead: void function(std::initializer_list<int> a) which will also accept function({1,2,3}) but will also accept other numbers of values, not just 3.

If you want to do C++, leave raw pointers and C arrays behind for a while.

If ypou are not going to change the array within the function then declare the function like
void function( const int ( &a )[3] );

For example
#include <iostream>

void function( const int ( &a )[3] ) 
{
    for (const auto &item : a)
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    function( { 1, 2, 3 } );
}

Otherwise use std::array<int, 3>
#include <array>

void function( std::array<int, 3> a ); 


Here's how I would start arrays with C++:

If I need fixed sized array, there's the std::array class:

#include <array>
#include <cstdint>

std::array<std::uint32_t, 4> four_quad_words {11, 22, 33, 44};


If I need a dynamic sized areay, there's std::vector:

#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>

//start with 5 elements:
std::vector<std::uint32_t> many_quad_words {1, 22, 333, 4444, 55555};
//append 5 more zeros to the end:
many_quad_words.resize(10);


If I need to call a function and pass the array by reference, there's std::span:

#include <span>
#include <cstdint>
#include <ranges>

void fill_two(std::span<std::unit32_t> words_by_ref){
    //Make all existing elements 2:
    std::ranges::fill(words_by_ref, 2);
};

fill_two(four_quad_words);//4 elements of value 2
fill_two(many_quad_words);//10 elements of value 2


If I need a reference to fixed sized array, there's the fixed sized span:

void fill_five(std::span<std::uint32_t, 4> four_words_by_ref){
    //make all four 5:
    std::ranges::fill(four_quad_words, 5);

fill_five(four_quad_words);//4 elements of value 5
//fill_two(many_quad_words);//Error!
};

If you need pass-by-value functions then just use std::array or std::vector as function arguments:
void foo(std::vector<std::uint32_t> vec);
void bar(std::array<std::uint32_t, 4> arr);

foo({111,22,3});
bar({1, 2, 3, 4});

Start fresh with C++ and leave C for much later in your self-tutor.
